# Multiple default parameters in function do not work

Tags: ruby, function, overloading

I am trying to understand why the below function gives compilation error:

```
# Works fine
def test(a, b=10, c=20)
    p a, b, c
end

# Works fine
def test(a=10, b=20, c)
    p a, b, c
end

# Gives error - syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
def test(a=10, b, c=20)
    p a, b, c
end
```

It seems multiple default parameters do not work if they are all not either at beginning or end of parameter list.

Comment: I think `def test(foo = nil, bar, baz = nil)` sums up your question.

Comment: There is major code-smell when you have multiple parameters to a method like you do. Instead, either define a structure, an object, or use a hash to define a wrapper or container for the options. This is really an XY problem: Your first question should be "How do I pass multiple required and optional parameters to a method." That answer would have solved this problem in advance.

Comment: @theTinMan My objective here is to understand why the function definitions are not working. I know it's bad code :)

Comment: Then please follow the guidelines about asking a question. Reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. You don't need ten parameters when two or three would work.

Comment: @ndn Why that function definition gives compilation error anyways?

Comment: @WandMaker, unfortunately, I don't know. I'm guessing there was an implementation obstacle and it wasn't worth working around it for something that probably has no practical implications. But still, it's a little ugly and inconsistent. I would definitely upvote whoever answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby allows mandatory and optional parameters to be defined in a flexible manner. These all work and are logical:

```
def foo(a); end 
def foo(a, b); end 
def foo(a, b=1); end
def foo(a=1, b); end
def foo(a=1, b=1); end
```

If you need three or four parameters, start considering whether you should switch to a different way of passing in the parameters. It's a maintenance and readability thing.

Instead of *anything* that looks like

```
def test(param1=nil, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10)
```

WAY before that point, switch to something more concise. Any of these would be preferable:

```
def foo(opts)
  a, b, c = opts.values_at(*%i[a b c]).map{ |v| v.nil? ? 'nil' : v }
  "a: '#{a}' b: '#{b}' c: '#{c}'"
end

foo(a:'a') # => "a: 'a' b: 'nil' c: 'nil'"
foo(a:'a', b:'b') # => "a: 'a' b: 'b' c: 'nil'"
foo(b:'b') # => "a: 'nil' b: 'b' c: 'nil'"
foo(a:'a', b:'b', c: 'c') # => "a: 'a' b: 'b' c: 'c'"
```

or:

```
Options = Struct.new('Options', 'a', 'b', 'c')

def foo(opts)
  a, b, c = opts.values.map{ |v| v.nil? ? 'nil' : v }
  "a: '#{a}' b: '#{b}' c: '#{c}'"
end

foo(Options.new('a', nil, 'c')) # => "a: 'a' b: 'nil' c: 'c'"
foo(Options.new('a', 'b', 'c')) # => "a: 'a' b: 'b' c: 'c'"
foo(Options.new(nil, 'b', 'c')) # => "a: 'nil' b: 'b' c: 'c'"
```

or:

```
require 'ostruct'

def foo(opts)
  a, b, c = opts.to_h.values_at(*%i[a b c]).map{ |v| v.nil? ? 'nil' : v }
  "a: '#{a}' b: '#{b}' c: '#{c}'"
end

foo(OpenStruct.new(:a => 'a')) # => "a: 'a' b: 'nil' c: 'nil'"
foo(OpenStruct.new(:a => 'a', :b => 'b')) # => "a: 'a' b: 'b' c: 'nil'"
foo(OpenStruct.new(:a => 'a', :b => 'b', :c => 'c')) # => "a: 'a' b: 'b' c: 'c'"
```

Using that sort of parameter passing greatly reduces the noise. Inside the method you can look for values that aren't initialized and force their default values and/or raise an error if you didn't receive a mandatory value.

Comment: Sorry!  @ndn and me tried to simplify the question - it does not have long param list part any more .

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the rules of parameter binding from [this answer related to default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328811/794242).

1. As long as there are unbound mandatory parameters at the beginning of the parameter list, bind arguments left-to-right
2. As long as there are unbound mandatory parameters at the end of the parameter list, bind arguments right-to-left
3. Any leftover arguments are bound to optional parameters left-to-right
4. Any leftover arguments are collected into an array and bound to the splat argument
5. A block is wrapped up into a `Proc` and bound to the block argument
6. If there are any unbound parameters or leftover arguments, `raise` an `ArgumentError`

If we read the above rules carefully, it seems to imply that:

> *If you don't have mandatory parameter(s) either at the beginning or end of parameter list, then, all parameters should be optional.*

Ruby seems to be enforcing the above rules in the below function definition:

```
# Gives error - syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
def test(a=10, b, c=10)
    p a, b, c
end
```

If one really needs optional parameters at beginning and end, one can use something like below - it uses default parameters at beginning and keyword parameters at end.

```
def test(a=10, b=20, c, d: 40, e: 40)
    p a, b, c, d, e
end

test (30)
#=> 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
```

However, below will not work:

```
def test(a=10, b=20, c, d: 40, e: 40, f)
    p a, b, c, d, e
end
# Will produce below error
# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER
# def test(a=10, b=20, c, d: 40, e: 40, f)
                                        ^
```